# Add a new RewriteRule in htaccess (CMS)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a CMS and want to modify the htaccess to add a new rewrite rule. The CMS already has the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) ./index.php
```

The new rule I would like to add should act as follows:

```
My_new_page/title_new_page/id -> target.php?id=$id
```

I tried as follows, but it didn't work out:

```
RewriteRule ^My_new_page/(.*)/(.*)$ target.php?id=$2
```

Now, the second rule works fine if I delete the first rule. However, I need the first rule to make the CMS work.
So they seem to somehow interfere each other.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `RewriteRule ^My_new_page/(.*)/(.*)$ target.php?id=$2` rule is *before* the CMS rule, otherwise the CMS rule will match against `My_new_page/title_new_page/id` and your rule never gets applied.